# How to change where programs are saved?

Tags: windows-10

I just reinstalled windows 10 on my new ssd and started reinstalling my programs. I have a 1tb hdd where I want to keep most of my files and programs. Some of the programs, for example the logitech software for my mouse and keyboard, didn't ask me where I want to install the software, it just installed it in the c drive, other programs like steam and battle.net asked me where I want to install. When I downloaded the logitech file from chrome, I downloaded it on my hdd and when I ran the exe file from my hdd it downloaded it into my c drive which I didn't want.

Also when I installed the drivers for my printer and microsoft office, no where during the install process did it ask me where to install, it just automatically installed on the c drive.

How can I choose where programs are installed when they don't ask me during installation?

Comment: Drivers are saved in SystemDrive that's obvious. But programs (like Chrome, Firefox etc as standalone) can be saved in other drives/partitions.

Comment: @Biswa why some programs like Microsoft office didn't ask me where to install?

Comment: Because that's how they're coded. There's no universal way to establish where everything is installed, you're going to need to research this on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: If you want to realize the performance benefits of your SSD you want your programs installed in the C: drive. Only your data goes on the 1tb and that is easily redirected by simply dragging and dropping your data folders (documents, pictures, desktop, etc.)

Comment: There is a registry entry that changes the location of The Program Files folder but Microsoft does not support or recommend it's use. It is designed for exceptional situations and not for general use. There are some serious issues with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has a number of specially defined folders [45 are shown for my PC]. You'll want to move the location for some of these to the HDD, particularly data, as @Appleoddity states, while leaving *Windows, Program Files,* etc. on the SSD. A quick way to *view* these predefined folders is with a tool such as [Nirsoft's Special Folders View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html).
[image: Nirsoft's Special Folders View]

Then, [change the location of specific folders](http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-change-the-location-of-user-folders-in-windows-10/):

- Open Windows File Explorer
- Right-click on a special folder and select *Properties*.
- On the *Location* tab, set the folder to the correct HDD (or SSD) directory.

[image: Changing special folder location]

Be sure to image a working configuration of both drives **before** making changes, as an error here can *really* mess up Windows!